# List of equations line break issue

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm trying to add dedicated list of figures.
The below solutions works fine but causes one stupid issue. As you can see on the following picture the usage causes that long formula descriptions lead to a break line but the second line doesn't start at the same position like the first line. How can I fix this to let them start at the same x-position or same offset?

Is there a way to align all "listof" or e.g. listoffigures to start at the same position?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{Formula\space\protect\numberline{\theequation} #1}}

\begin{document}



\begin{equation}
    2 + 2 = 4
    \label{eq:second}
    \myequations{this text is quite tooooooooooooooo long for a single row and needs a second one!}
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \label{Pic}
    \caption{example}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\listoffigures
\listofmyequations

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Formula” should go inside the argument to `\numberline`; you can set the label width to be wide enough to contain “Formula x.y” (you'll need to adjust this when the document is in its final form and you'll know the figures).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{Formula \theequation}\ignorespaces#1}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \settowidth{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{Formula 0.00}%
}

\begin{document}



\begin{equation}
    2 + 2 = 4
    \label{eq:second}
    \myequations{this text is quite tooooooooooooooo long for a single row and needs a second one!}
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \label{Pic}
    \caption{example}
\end{figure}

\newpage

\listoffigures
\listofmyequations

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!